# Add contribution option to petition?

Tags: contributions, petition

We are planning to put up a petition and want to add the option for signers to donate to support our work.

Is there a way to include a donation option on the petition page, or another way to direct signers to a contribution page after signing?

Comment: I think you can add some html to the thank you page so you could add a CTA to direct to a contribution page but not aware of any other options.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that might be an option -- I think you may be right, this may be my only way to go.